# How to set google map loading tiles color?

Tags: android, google-maps

Bright loading tiles on map with dark style don't look good. Is there a way to change loading tiles colour?

Comment: Have you tried simply changing the background color of the fragment?

Comment: @MatPag I tried but it didn't help

Comment: I've fear there is no way actually to change the loading tiles color... :\

Comment: GMapOptions.backgroundColor, introduced in 2.119,  you can change the background color of the tiles that appear before tiles load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `GoogleMap.setMapStyle` to change the theme of the map, try like this,

```
try {
            // Customise the styling of the base map using a JSON object defined
            // in a raw resource file.
            boolean success = googleMap.setMapStyle(
                    MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                            this, R.raw.style_json));

            if (!success) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Style parsing failed.");
            }
        } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Can't find style. Error: ", e);
        }
```

You can get the json file from this [official map style site](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/) and you can put that json file into your app raw folder

Complete explanation for styling the map in android you can refer in [official site](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/styling)

Sample `style_json`

```
[
  {
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#212121"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#757575"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#212121"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.country",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#9e9e9e"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.locality",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#bdbdbd"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#757575"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#181818"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#616161"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#1b1b1b"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#2c2c2c"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#8a8a8a"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#373737"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#3c3c3c"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway.controlled_access",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#4e4e4e"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.local",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#616161"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#757575"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#000000"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#3d3d3d"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 4):

I faced with the same headache, managed solving it through the fragment XML res:

```
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_google_map"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:backgroundColor="@color/primaryBlue"/>
```

Comment: damn, this is actually working.

Comment: Works for MapView as well. This should have been the accepted answer.

Comment: So obvious, and I missed that. Works perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Concept:**

Tile is a rectangular in strcuture and it holds the image data. `Tile` ([link](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Tile)) is provided by `TileProvider` ([link](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/TileProvider)).  `TileProvider` is a class that provides the tile images for a `TileOverlay` ([link](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/TileOverlay)).

Note: Overlay is transparent in nature, which has x, y, and z axis. It's like and transparent glass in front of you.

TileProvider provides Tile just behind the TileOverlay just like you put your book below the transparent glass. In the z-axis of the `TileOverlay`, there are set of layers like  `GroundOverlays`, `Circles`, `Polylines`, and `Polygons`. It means `GroundOverlays` is at the last layer, and it is most opaque. You provide your customized image and change the color in `GroundOverlay`. You also maintain all the other top layers' transparency, visibility etc. properties. In this way, you change the tile color.

**Now, your main task is to create your customized GroundOverlay.**
You `GroundOverlay` image is provided as `BitmapDescriptor`. You use `BitmapDescriptorFactory` to create your custom `BitmapDescriptor` image as below.

```
BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.current_position_tennis_ball)
```

/* You see, `current_position_tennis_ball drawable resource`, now, you used as your `Tile` color */

**Implementation:**

**Note**: MOON_MAP_URL_FORMAT is a`enter code here` jpg image, and `tileProvider` is referencing that image (actually a customized image)

```
private static final String MOON_MAP_URL_FORMAT =
                "http://mw1.google.com/mw-planetary/lunar/lunarmaps_v1/clem_bw/%d/%d/%d.jpg";
```

**/* provider the bright jpg above */**

```
    TileProvider tileProvider /* ultimately it is an image */ = new UrlTileProvider(256, 256) {
                @Override
                public synchronized URL getTileUrl(int x, int y, int zoom) {
                    // The moon tile coordinate system is reversed.  This is not normal.
                    int reversedY = (1 << zoom) - y - 1;
                    String s = String.format(Locale.US, MOON_MAP_URL_FORMAT, zoom, x, reversedY);
                    URL url = null;
                    try {
                        url = new URL(s);
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        throw new AssertionError(e);
                    }
                return url;
            }
        };
```

You can see the complete source code [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/TileOverlayDemoActivity.java).

Comment: hmm, thanks, this sounded promising. But something is not working out exactly. The image (the url of which I replaced because the moon gives a 404) appears on top of the map, although under the pin.

In the source you added, it is added with this:
'mMoonTiles = map.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(tileProvider));', not GroundOverlayOptions, which doesn't seem to use tileProvider

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"), { backgroundColor: "#000000" });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am coding native app for android

Answer (score 0):

You say in a comment "I am coding native app for android", but that is not reflected in your Tags (android, google-maps) or title or question.
If you are using the Ionic native 4.0 Framework [ionicframework](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-maps/)  then:

```
 setBackgroundColor(color); //Specifies the background color of the app.
```

Comment: "A native application (native app) is an application program that has been developed for use on a particular platform or device." - I write my app in Kotlin using Android SDK

Comment: @raver A native application is binary that runs on the CPU of the device without translation, i.e. Java is not native on any Android device (because it is translated) libraries (i.e.. .so) are native, as are executables. Jar files are NOT native. If what you are saying is true, EVERYTHING is native that can be run on the device, thus making the term meaningless.

Comment: So how can I call an app written without using frameworks like ionic?

Comment: @raver the term native is much overused, with different meanings for different people, when you use it it must convey a specific meaning, otherwise don't use it. Iionic is not native (you don't have to compile it for every cpu) in my narrow definition. See https://www.howtogeek.com/163759/what-does-it-mean-for-software-to-run-natively/

Comment: You didn't answer my previous question :). "Native android app" is commonly used, so I will stick with it

Comment: "So how can I call an app written without using frameworks like ionic?" I don't understand your question. But what meaning are you trying to convey ?, It's confusing, don't use native unless the meaning is clear. Anyway this is not the place for a debate, there are stack overflow meta sites for that e.g   .https://meta.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Create `mapLabelStyle.json` into your app `raw folder`. Copy this json style into that file.

```
[
  {
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "lightness": 5
      },
      {
        "visibility": "simplified"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.text",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#400040"           //You can change color of your choice
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Then set style using below code.

```
GoogleMap.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this,R.raw.mapLabelStyle));
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, but this changes, as it states in your code, the color of the labels, not the tiles.

Comment: @Jakob. Not sure about changing color. But Set transparency might solve your problem. It can be useful to overlay transparent tiles on the map, so that users can see the base map below the overlaid tiles. `mTileOverlay = map.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions()
            .tileProvider(new UrlTileProvider() {...})
            .transparency(0.5f));` and then `mTileOverlay.setTransparency(0.5f - mTileOverlay.getTransparency());`.  It will toggles the tile overlay's transparency between `0.5f` and `0.0f`